# String not recognized as valid datetime when convertring with ParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to take a string and convert it to a `DateTime`, but no matter what I try, I always get

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

I am trying to use `DateTime.ParseExact` but no matter what I have passed in as the format string I always get this error. I tired assigning the variable I am converting to a string to confirm the format and it is coming back as

```
10/11/2016 10:04:51 AM
```

What am I missing here?

```
var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(path);

var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);

var excelData = excelFile.WorksheetRange("A6", "N16384", "Alarm Report")
                            .Select(row => new MTNAlarm()
                            {
                                AlarmDescription = row["Raised"],
                                //AlarmStatus = row["Alarm Status"],
                                //ContainingFolder = row["Containing Folder"],
                                //DeviceName = row["Device Name"],
                                //DeviceType = row["Device Type"],
                                //FullPath = row["Full Device Path"],
                                //IPAddress = row["IP Address"],
                                //IsCleared = (row["Cleared"] == "N/A") ? true : false,
                                //IsIgnored = (row["Ignored"] == "N/A") ? true : false,
                                //IsTrap = (row["Is Trap"] == "True") ? true : false,
                                Raised = DateTime.ParseExact(row["Raised"], "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", culture),
                                //Severity = row["Severity"],
                                //SitePortalAlarmID = int.Parse(row["Alarm ID"]),
                                //LocationID = 0,
                            }).ToList();
```

I have tried:

```
MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm
```

Comment: stop it before it errors, and type row["Raised"] into the watch window, are you sure the string is coming back as "10/11/2016 10:04:51 AM"?

Comment: @Dispersia Not sure how to do that, or what the watch window is. What I did do was comment out the conversion and just read `AlarmDescription = row["Raised"],` value and saw that `AlarmDescription` was set to "10/11/2016 10:04:51 AM"

Comment: Set a variable to row["Raised"] before it goes in, set AlarmDescription as it and the Raised as what you currently have but replace the hard code with that value. It's possible it clears the data after it calls it once or something? But it won't throw if that is the EXACT string.

Comment: I am not sure how to do what your asking. The variable is coming in form and excel file and the only way I know to read that variable is to do the LINQ query in my code. I have put a break point on the line right after the LINQ query so after the `excelData` variable is filled I can use debugger to look into that and with I set `AlarmDescription = row["Raised"]` I can see `AlarmDescription` has value "10/11/2016 10:04:51 AM"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is not a question any more

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with Excel dates, the date can either be stored as a string representation of a date, or it may be an [OA date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) (OLE Automation Date). I've found that checking for both types is the safest route when parsing Excel dates.

Here's an extension method I wrote for the conversion:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sometimes the date from Excel is a string, other times it is an OA Date:
/// Excel stores date values as a Double representing the number of days from January 1, 1900.
/// Need to use the FromOADate method which takes a Double and converts to a Date.
/// OA = OLE Automation compatible.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="date">a string to parse into a date</param>
/// <returns>a DateTime value; if the string could not be parsed, returns DateTime.MinValue</returns>
public static DateTime ParseExcelDate( this string date )
{
    DateTime dt;
    if( DateTime.TryParse( date, out dt ) )
    {
        return dt;
    }

    double oaDate;
    if( double.TryParse( date, out oaDate ) )
    {
        return DateTime.FromOADate( oaDate );
    }

    return DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

In your example, the usage would be:

```
Raised = row["Raised"].ParseExcelDate()
```

Based on the culture, you may need to modify the extension method to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("10/11/2016 10:04:51 AM", 
                             "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Not the downvoter but how does this code help me? As you can see in my OP I have tried that format but I still get the error.

Comment: @Matthew I don't know what you have tried, but I tested above code before posting....

Comment: The two cultures differ between your solution and OP's code - could that be it?

Comment: @L.B. Then read the entire post, I list the 4 formats I tried. This was one of them and it is not working in my LINQ code.

Comment: @Matthew What is so hard to understand.... **I tested it before posting**. Why don't you copy&paste and then test the code.

Comment: @L.B `Console.Writeline("Hello World!");` works too, that doesn't mean it helps the OP in any way, shape, or form. In no way does this answer his question and you posted literally exactly what he already has just with a different culture (of which won't change anything in this regard).

Comment: @L.B I just tested it with `Raised = DateTime.ParseExact(row["Raised"], "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),` and get the same error.

Comment: @Dispersia this answer doesn't get `String was not recongnized as a valid DateTime.` and return a valid date. Is this enough?

Comment: @L.B neither does the code in my comment. So no. Yours doesn't show an issue with the variable it's using. He can't just hard-code the value, it's obviously being pulled from a DB.

Comment: @Matthew  You test it with `row["Raised"]`. So if it may be different then you posted in your question and get an exception.. See the date string again.... Just Copy my code and test it. Do you get an exception? If not, then post the real date string....

Comment: @L.B My testing says the real string is "10/11/2016 10:04:51 AM". This test was done by setting a break point after the LINQ query, assing `row@"raised"] to `AlarmDescription` inspecting `excelData` and seeing the value of `AlarmDescription`. This is the method I have always used to see what value are being pulled by a LINQ query, if there is some flaw in this that is giving me the wrong value please give me the correct way.

Comment: @Matthew `My testing says the real string is ... ` Let's go one by one.  You still didn't answer. Does my code work or not?

Comment: @Matthew Then  we may assume your string in `row["Raised"]` is not the same as you posted. Am I correct?  (I read your comment before you deleted it. Of course I knew it)

Comment: @Matthew Now the problem is determining what  you get in `row["Raised"]` really...

Comment: @Matthew Maybe we should start with how to use the VS debugger....